# Firewall Rules For OpenVZ VPS?

Tags: firewall, vps, linux, openvz

I'm in the process of setting up a VPS server that I eventually plan to use for light web and email server operations.

I'd like it to be reasonably secure but I'm not all that familiar with iptables.  Is there an easier way to configure the firewall access?

Thanks,

M

Comment: What kind of extra security gain are you after? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more user-friendly approach to iptables that I've used is [the CSF firewall](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html). However there is one big caveat for you since you are running an OpenVZ VPS - the use of iptables at a VPS level requires your Hosting Provider to make some changes (See [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/129429/openvz-and-iptables) & [here](http://forum.configserver.com/viewtopic.php?p=5084&postcount=6)) at the Host Node (ie, physical server hosting your VPS) level. Unless they are willing to do that, you won't have much luck.

Comment: Thanks. iptables seems to be working out for now.  I'm finding it a little tedious but otherwise it works well... I miss Xen =)